# Notificacion cuando mi sensor detecte la señal en android studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, arduino

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el cual se basa un sensor de fuego, es decir cuando detecte me envie una notificación al celular, estoy desarrollando la aplicación con Firebase y android studio estoy estancado en esa parte y no puedo solucionarlo, estoy utilizando un Nodemcu para hacer la señal, la cuestion es como desarrollar la parte en android studio para la notificación

Comment: Alex bienvenido a la comunidad te sugiero mejores tu pregunta ya que no detallas que has intentado realizar en Android o Firebase te recomiendo sigas esta [guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

A tu pregunta le faltan detalles, pero creo que puedo entender que es, lo que quieres hacer es algo similar a un dispositivo IoT.

Lo que necesitas es un medio que reciba la notificación del ESP(NodeMCU) y que sea este quien la envíe a la aplicación. Una manera es crear un servidor, que el ESP se conecte a este mediante HTTP, envíe un post y luego el servidor envíe la señal a la aplicación. Yo te recomiendo usar el protocolo MQTT en vez del HTTP, MQTT es mucho más rápido y ligero, además de que te ahorras espacio de memoria del ESP. Puedes conectar el ESP y el servidor a la red MQTT, el servidor será el medio entre tu app y el ESP.

Si usted no tiene mucha experiencia programando del lado del servidor, le recomiendo usar Node-RED, que se programa de manera visual, en bloques, muy util para proyectos IoT debido a su facilidad y versatilidad de uso. Puede hacer conexiones de: HTTP, MQTT y WebSockets. Puedes leer más en la página de [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/)

En cuanto a la parte de la notificación en la app, debes hacer que tu app se conecte al servidor para recibir la notificación. Puedes usar una conexión HTTP o una WebSockets. Pero, si no tienes mucha experiencia en esto, también puedes usar aplicaciones de código abierto como [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/), tiene una aplicación de servidor y una para Android, puedes usar esto para hacer todo tu proyecto, ya que también tiene una librería para el ESP8266, mira un [video aquí (inglés)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV_X3e7xwDE).

Realmente no te puedo ayudar más debido a lo ambigua que es tu pregunta, pero al menos espero haberte dado una idea de lo que podrías hacer.